# Python Threading More then one agrument given

Tags: python, multithreading, arguments

I am trying to start threads and I keep getting and error message saying that I am trying to send more than one argument. It seems like the Thread object does not take the variable port as one argument but rather each character in the string as one separate argument. How is this working ? It is my first time multithreading in python.

Error message:

```
Exception in thread /dev/ttyUSB0:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: report() takes exactly 1 argument (12 given)
```

Code:

```
def report(port):
    print("\n")
    print(st() +"Connecting to" + port[0]) 

    device = serial.Serial(port=port[0], baudrate=9600, timeout=0.2)

    print (st() + "Connection sucessfull...")       
    print (st() + "Initializing router on "+ port[0])
    if initialize_router(device) == 0:
        return 0

    print (st() + "Initialization sucessfull")
    print (st() + "Starting to inject IP basic config")
    if inject_config(device) == 0:
        print(errror("injecing the confing",port[0]))
        return 0

    print(st()+ "Finished injecting default IP setting on router connected to " + port[0])

    return 1

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    ports = list_ports.comports()
    list_port = list(ports)
    port_counter = -1
    for port in list_port:
        if "USB" in port[0]:
            port_counter = port_counter + 1
            port = "/dev/ttyUSB" + str(port_counter)
            thread = Thread(target=report, args=(port), name=port)
            thread.start()
            print port
            print ("\n")
            continue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        thread = Thread(target=report, args=(port), name=port)
```

I'm guessing you wanted to pass a single element tuple to `args` here. But those parentheses around `port` have no effect by themselves. Try:

```
        thread = Thread(target=report, args=(port,), name=port)
```

Comment: still get the same thing ... here is the error code: 
Exception in thread /dev/ttyUSB0:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: report() takes exactly 1 argument (12 given)

Comment: Strange, the syntax I'm using here works on my simple test example... To debug further, I will need a [mcve].

Comment: @Kevin's answer is the only one that makes sense. Are you 100% sure you added the trailing comma *inside* the parens around  `port` when passing `args`, and that you're running the code with that modification? Because the precise error you see is what you'd get if you omitted it (down to the exact number of args given, since the string is length 12). Also, inside your function, you seem to assume `port` will be a `tuple` (using `port[0]` to get it) which it will not be; it gets unpacked when the thread function is called.